# main Layout Overlaps with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i am new with navigation drawer. I want to Create layout for my mainactivity, but why overlap so my main layout not visible, may you help me. Thanks for answer

This is my activity_main.xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jaakkk"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I do to change that?

Comment: what changes you did...and what changes you want...?

Comment: i just wanna set textView on that

Comment: i checked it...your textView is appear behind the NavigationView.

Comment: oh, thanks, i must mist on that

Comment: What you want actual

Comment: write your Text  Like:- Jaakkkkkkkkkkk instead your Jaakk you will also see.your Textview behind your NavigationView.

Answer (score 2):

So, your problem is drawer layout overlapping the linear layout below. Use

u can add this line in

`<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:layout_below="@id/drawer_layout"`/>

Comment: Don't make 2 answers.. Just edit your 1st one ..or include this too.

Comment: where exactly i add this?

Comment: still same, i can't see main activity.